# SQL Server : when aggregating, select a single row's value for a specific column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, aggregate, aggregate-functions

There are three columns in my table, `Contract_number`, `Revenue` and `Cust_name`. I'd like to `SUM(Revenue)` while grouping by the `Contract_number` to get the total revenue for that contract. Next to this, I want to display `Cust_name` to show which customer is under that contract.

The problem is there are multiple `Cust_name` values under any given contract. The `Cust_name` values underneath a contract are all extremely similar and I don't care which one of them is used, I just want to display one of them.

If I use something like `MIN(Cust_name)`, I lose data, and if I do `GROUP BY Cust_name`, then the values are split into multiple rows.

Is there a way to add a single `Cust_name` value to each result while keep the `Contract_number` and `Revenue` aggregate functions the same?

Comment: Use MAX(Cust_Name)

Comment: more like three columns rather rows

Comment: I think you better **normalize** your table, why you have a lot of similar Cust_Names for a single Contract_Number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use MIN(Cust_Name) or MAX(Cust_Name) together with SUM(Revenue) then GROUP BY Contract_number

```
SELECT Contract_number,
       SUM(Revenue),
       MIN(Cust_Name) -- or MAX(Cust_Name)
  FROM table
 GROUP BY Contract_number
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. My query actually contains a subquery too. When I used MIN in the subquery I lost results but when I put only the main query it worked perfect. Thank you Ferdinand!